# Add missing characters to sentences

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing

I'm working text in python and have several cases of missing characters, as like:

```
test_list = ['people can t believe','we couldn t be happier','let s not forget']
```

In test_list all apostrophes are missing, I wrote a function to add it again:

```
def add_apostrophe(sentense):
    words = sentense.split()
    fixed_s = []
    flag = False
    buffer_ = ''
    for w in reversed(words):
        if flag:
            fixed_s.append(''.join([w,buffer_]))
            flag = False
            buffer_ = ''
        elif  w in ['t','s']:
            flag = True
            buffer_ = "'{}".format(w)
        else:
            fixed_s.append(w)
    fixed_s = ' '.join(reversed(fixed_s))
    return fixed_s
```

this kind of works:

```
[add_apostrophe(s) for s in test_list]

["people can't believe", "we couldn't be happier", "let's not forget"]
```

But I think this could break the sentences for some cases, I haven't made an exhaustive test of it.
 Also, this seems like a common issue, the is some library to restore missing apostrophes and some other characters?

Comment: Check this link. Maybe you can get some clue from here: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/nov13/challenges/punctuation-corrector-its/leaderboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with regex. But this might not be the exhaustive coverage.

```
import re
test_list = ['people can t believe','we couldn t be happier','let s not forget']
print [re.sub(r"(\s?)([a-zA-Z]+)\s([a-zA-Z]{1})\s",r"\1\2'\3 ", a) for a in test_list]
```

Output:

```
["people can't believe", "we couldn't be happier", "let's not forget"]
```

Regex explanation:

(\s?)([a-zA-Z]+)\s([a-zA-Z]{1})\s

(\s?) - Matches and captures 0 or 1 space as group 1.
([a-zA-Z]+) - Matches and caputres 1 or more letters as group 2
\s - Matches 1 space
([a-zA-Z]{1}) - Matches and captures 1 letter as group 3
\s - Matches 1 space

\1, \2 and \3 - group 1, group 2 and group 3